# Can't Swap Languages When Textbox is Focused (Microsoft Edge)

Tags: html, windows-10, focus, microsoft-edge

This has to be a programming question, relevant for stack-overflow, but there might be something I'm missing.

**So, has anybody else observed this problem?**

(This would be easily recreatable only to people who use multiple languages regularly.)

**My problem is this**: to swap between my two languages, I normally use the `alt+shift` shortcut. This works everywhere, for example it works in MS office, chrome and firefox, notepad, visual studio... it even works on the Microsoft Edge's search bar. However, when I am typing **in an html element in Microsoft Edge in Windows 10**, it doesn't.

Until now I have to either change the language from the taskbar, using the mouse (which is slow), or take the focus off the control, use the shortcut, and give the focus back to the control (which is slow but also annoying)

**Anybody know to help me with this?**

I'm interested in understanding what's wrong more than solving it, since I can always use another browser.

PS: If I was as frustrated as I am now, I would whine about how Microsoft manages to keep making things that everybody else has solved ages ago, difficult.

Comment: Hey, what version of Edge are you using? I couldn't repro this using Win+Space or Alt+Shift. Additionally, if you wouldn't mind sharing a page where it does repro so that we are trying it on the same textbox. Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299

Sign in page of edx.org is an example page.

I should also clarify that sometimes it does work, I cannot find out why though.

Comment: Crap, transient bugs are the worse - at any rate - there isn't going to be a work around for this that you can apply since you don't own the site. I will reach out to my colleague, but if you wouldn't mind opening a bug on bugs.microsoftedge.com with detailed repro steps, we would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.